# SAP GUI 7.70 Screen Painter

Tags: sap-gui, dynpro

I am facing an issue, after creating screen in my program, when I click Layout, the Screen Painter tool opens up and when I am done declaring objects I try to activate and my whole SAP GUI lags. I have to close SAP GUI and again I have to logon. Can anyone tell me why this problem coming. I have SAP GUI 7.70.

Comment: what means "lags"? give screenshot. Generally after adding objects in painter you should press activate button, close the painter and the press enter in gui popup

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Suncatcher thank you for the solution, I have found that after pressing the activation icon in screen painter there is one gui pop up arises on which we have to click to activate and then we have to came back again in screen painter and again we have to press that activation icon and then close our screen painter and then its got activated.